# Ajax Request Not Always Consistent

Tags: javascript, ajax, math

I have been developing a site that will provide schedules created by people. I'm using Alienware to develop it and the ajax code works perfectly on the laptop all of the time. I am using IE. However, if I access my site on my Samsung Smart TV or my HTC U11 phone, Ajax isn't consistent. It displays the data I am requesting, however, when I sum up a total of hours for the week, it sometimes displays the correct hours, or sometimes shows 0 hours, when the user is scheduled for the week. Why is it inconsistent between devices? I know that Ajax is recommended for IE. As I said, though, it sometimes will display the correct total weekly hours, and other times it will just show zero. This issue isn't occurring on my Alienware.

I've already tried using onload instead of onreadystatechange. I've set the request to asynchronous and synchronous. Whether it's set to true or false, on my other devices, it fails to be consistent. I've tried it as a post and get method, and both also are inconsistent. What is wrong with my code?

```
function getThisWeek(str5) {

    lastDate = new Date(str5);

    // getting dates for this week to be displayed...

    this.math = dayInput.length - 1;

    this.math0 = 0 - new Date(str5).getDay();

    // getting week total hour length, to determine how many times this code executes...
    weekSum = 0;
    totals = [];
    for (this.i = 0; this.i < weekTotalHours.length; this.i++) {

        str3 = this.i;
        this.date = new Date(str5);
        for (this.ii = (this.i * (7)) - new Date().getDay(); this.ii < (7 * (this.i + 1)) - new Date().getDay(); this.ii++) {

            totalHours = 0;

            this.date = new Date(str5);
            this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + (this.ii)));

            // which element position the total daily hours belongs to when displaying them...
            this.pos = this.ii + new Date().getDay();
            thisDayChart[this.pos].innerHTML = "";

                // displaying the date
                dayInput[this.pos].innerHTML = this.date.getDate();

                // highlighting today's date...
                if (this.date.getDate() == new Date(str5).getDate() && this.date.getMonth() == new Date().getMonth()) {
                dayInput[this.pos].style.color = "white";
                dayInput[this.pos].style.backgroundColor = "silver";
                dayInput[this.pos].style.borderRadius = "0px";
                thisDay[this.pos].style.border = "2px double lightblue";
                } else {
                dayInput[this.pos].style.color = "";
                dayInput[this.pos].style.backgroundColor = "";
                dayInput[this.pos].style.borderRadius = "";
                thisDay[this.pos].style.border = "";
                }

            // getting schedule from database...

            this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            this.xmlhttp.pos = this.pos;
            this.xmlhttp.ipos = this.i;
            this.xmlhttp.d = months[this.date.getMonth()] + " " + this.date.getDate() + ", " + this.date.getFullYear();
            this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    //alert(this.responseText);

                    dayInput[this.pos].m = months[new Date(this.d).getMonth()];
                    dayInput[this.pos].weekDay = days[new Date(this.d).getDay()];

                    // how many weeks in the year is user...

                    this.islpyr = new Date(this.d);
                    this.islpyr = this.islpyr.setMonth(1);
                    this.islpyr = new Date(new Date(this.islpyr).setDate(29));

                    if (this.islpyr.getMonth() == 2) {
                    mlens[1] = 28;
                    } else {
                    mlens[1] = 29;
                    }

                    // getting total amount of days for the year...
                    this.yrlen = 0;
                    for (this.iii = 0; this.iii < mlens.length; this.iii++) {
                        this.yrlen += mlens[this.iii];
                    }

                    // getting total weeks
                    this.wklen = this.yrlen / 7;
                    this.wklen = Math.round(this.wklen);

                    this.week = 0;
                    for (this.iii = 0; this.iii < new Date(this.d).getMonth(); this.iii++) {

                        this.week += mlens[this.iii];

                    }
                    this.week += new Date(this.d).getDate();

                    this.week /= 7;
                    this.week = Math.round(this.week) + 1;
                    // rounding and displaying current week number...

                    if (new Date(this.d).getDay() == 0) {
                    myDayWrapper[this.ipos].weekLabel = "Week " + this.week + " of " + this.wklen;
                    }

                    if (this.pos == 0) {
                    weekDisplay[0].innerHTML = myDayWrapper[0].weekLabel;
                    }

                    // which day of the year it is... how many days in the year is the user...

                    this.yrpos = 0;
                    for (this.iv = 0; this.iv < new Date(this.d).getMonth(); this.iv++) {

                        this.yrpos += mlens[this.iv];

                    }

                    this.yrpos += new Date(this.d).getDate();

                    thisDayTitle[this.pos].innerHTML = "Day " + this.yrpos + " of " + this.yrlen;

                    totalHours = 0;

                    this.schedule = "" + this.responseText;

                    // if user is unscheduled, do this first... 'undefined' literally means there isn't a schedule for that specific day.
                    if (this.schedule.search("Undefined") >= 0) {

                        this.elem = document.createElement("div");
                        this.elem.setAttribute("class","not_scheduled");
                        this.elem.innerHTML = "Unscheduled";
                        thisDayChart[this.pos].appendChild(this.elem);

                        this.elem = document.createElement("div");
                        this.elem.setAttribute("class","pick_up_shift_btn");
                        this.elem.innerHTML = "Claim Shifts";
                        this.elem.i = this.pos;
                        this.elem.ipos = this.ipos;

                            this.elem.onclick = function() {

                                popUpWrap[1].style.display = "block";
                                this.datesd = [];
                                for (this.i = this.ipos * 7; this.i < 7 * (this.ipos + 1); this.i++) {
                                this.datesd.push(dayInput[this.i].innerHTML);
                                }

                                for (this.i = 0; this.i < 7; this.i++) {

                                shiftClaimDate[this.i].innerHTML = this.datesd[this.i];
                                popUpShiftDay[this.i].innerHTML = dayInput[this.i].weekDay;
                                this.strrr = "" + dayInput[this.i].m;
                                this.strrr = this.strrr.substring(0,3);
                                shiftClaimMonth[this.i].innerHTML = this.strrr;
                                }

                            }

                        thisDayChart[this.pos].appendChild(this.elem);

                        if (totals.length - 1 == this.pos) {
                        } else {
                        totals.push(0);
                        }

                    } else {

                        // getting daily total...

                        this.schedule = this.schedule.split(",");
                        for (this.iii = 0; this.iii < this.schedule.length; this.iii++) {

                            this.str = "" + this.schedule[this.iii];
                            this.str = this.str.split("=");

                            this.dateString = "December 22, 1991";
                            switch (this.str[0]) {

                                case "shift_start":

                                    this.start = new Date(this.dateString + " " + this.str[1]);
                                    this.end = this.schedule[this.schedule.length - 1] + "";
                                    this.end = this.end.split("=");
                                    this.end = new Date(this.dateString + " " + this.end[1]);

                                    this.hours = (this.end.getHours() - this.start.getHours()) * 60;
                                    this.hours = this.hours - (this.start.getMinutes() + this.end.getMinutes());
                                    this.hours /= 60;

                                    totalHours += this.hours;

                                    weekSum += totalHours;

                                break;

                                case "break_start":

                                    this.start = new Date(this.dateString + " " + this.str[1]);
                                    this.end = this.schedule[this.iii + 1] + "";
                                    this.end = this.end.split("=");
                                    this.end = new Date(this.dateString + " " + this.end[1]);

                                    this.hours = (this.end.getHours() - this.start.getHours()) * 60;
                                    this.hours = this.hours - (this.start.getMinutes() + this.end.getMinutes());
                                    this.hours /= 60;

                                    weekSum -= this.hours;
                                    totalHours -= this.hours;

                                    this.s = "s";
                                    if (totalHours == 1) {
                                    this.s = "";
                                    }


                                    thisDayChart[this.pos].innerHTML = totalHours + " hour" + this.s;

                                break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    weekTotalHours[this.ipos].innerHTML = "Week Total: " + weekSum;
                    //alert(weekSum);
                   // displaying hour totals...
                    if (new Date(this.d).getDay() == 6) {
                    weekSum = 0;
                    }
                    totalHours = 0;
                }


            }

            this.xmlhttp.open("GET","/js/data/schedule.html?date="+ months[this.date.getMonth()] + " " + this.date.getDate() + ", " + this.date.getFullYear(),false);
            this.xmlhttp.send();

        }

    }

}
```

I expect every device to be consistent with the hour total it should be displaying, on every device that Ajax should work on.

Comment: There's far too much fiddly code here to go and analyse every line for problems, but as an overall sense I'd say this is unlikely to be related to AJAX (that's just a means of sending data to/from the server) and far more likely to be related to differences in the JS Date implementation across different browsers and platforms, causing bugs in calculations. If you give us clearer information we might be able to be more certain (e.g. you say it "sometimes" gives the wrong answer...that's too vague. Pin down the exact scenarios, so you've got a list of the factors which appear to affect it)

Comment: P.S. you may be able to use emulators (e.g. provided by people like BrowserStack and others, or in some IDEs) to be able to actually debug the JS running on these devices, and see line-by-line where the calculations start to go wrong. You'll also be able to see if you _are_ getting any AJAX errors, but I think that's less likely - if ajax requests were failing, the code would probably just crash without returning any results at all).

Comment: As an advance recommendation (assuming my prediction is correct), you might want to consider using a date library such as [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) (there are others two) which has some built-in fixes for cross-platform differences, and also simplifies the syntax and process of dealing with dates in general - you can probably make your code a lot shorter and easier to maintain at the same time.

Comment: '(e.g. you say it "sometimes" gives the wrong answer...that's too vague' - quote.  I literally mean that the code chooses to not display the correct amount of weekly hours. When I say sometimes, I literally mean sometimes. Every few refreshes of the page it displays zero, but the other times I refresh the page it displays the exact amount of hours.

Comment: @David Please do some debugging (logs, alerts, simplifications, given that the smart tv probably doesn't feature a debugger) as to why it "displays zero". Where *exactly* does the calculation go wrong, at which step do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: I think it's what you suggested prior to this, I think it was the date issue. I think I'm working on a solution. Thank you.

Comment: " Every few refreshes of the page it displays zero, but the other times I refresh the page it displays the exact amount of hours" ...ok but computers don't behave randomly. There will be a pattern, you just need to find out what it is. We can't run your code in the necessary environment, so we can't do that for you.

Comment: But yes, I'd be 90% sure it's differences in the Date implementations. I'd highly recommend momentJS, like I said it can be used make your overall code a lot simpler (e.g. no need for crazy string manipulations, doing common date-related calculations for you via its various functions), as well as dealing with the cross-browser issues for you.